# Django - get serialized fields from related model

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-views

I can't figure out how to serialize a query that includes fields from a reverse related model. My models look like this. Every vote is linked to a single album:

```
# models.py

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Vote(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_vote = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

What I'd like to do is perform a query that returns all Album objects, as well as a sum of the votes attributed to that album. That's easy enough, but when I serialize the query, the "total_votes" field is lost:

```
# views.py

# this works fine
query = Album.objects.annotate(total_votes = Sum(vote__user_vote))

# after serialization, I lose the field "total_votes"
serialized = serializers.serialize('json', list(query))
return serialized
```

Unfortunately, the field "total_votes" doesn't appear in the serialized result  since, according to Django documentation, "only the fields that are locally defined on the model will be serialized."

So my question is, how do I get the following serialized result (assuming there are 100 votes for Abbey Road and 150 for Astral Weeks)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
{
  "pk": 1,
  "model": "app.album",
  "fields": {
    "name": "Abbey Road",
    "total_votes": 100
},
{
  "pk": 2,
  "model": "app.album",
  "fields": {
    "name": "Astral Weeks",
    "total_votes": 150
},
...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the source, there’s no way to do this using `serializers.serialize`.  The base django serializer will only serialize `local_fields` on the model instance:

```
        for field in concrete_model._meta.local_fields:
            if field.serialize:
                if field.remote_field is None:
                    if self.selected_fields is None or field.attname in self.selected_fields:
                        self.handle_field(obj, field)
                else:
                    if self.selected_fields is None or field.attname[:-3] in self.selected_fields:
                        self.handle_fk_field(obj, field)
        for field in concrete_model._meta.many_to_many:
            if field.serialize:
                if self.selected_fields is None or field.attname in self.selected_fields:
                    self.handle_m2m_field(obj, field)
```

In order to get what you want, you’d have to roll your own serialization function (e.g., something that converts your model to a dict and then uses the DjangoJSONEncoder).